# Let $E$ be the spliting field of $x^{p^n} - x$ over $\Bbb{Z}_p$ then $E$ has charateristic $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Prove if $E$ be the spliting field of $x^{p^n} - x$ over $\Bbb{Z}_p$ then $E$ has charateristic $p$. where $p$ is some prime number.

My attempt:
First, assume $E$ be a finite field, therefore the character is some prime number $q$, and the order of $E$ is $q^n$ for some positive integer $n$. Since $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is subfield of $E$ , therefore $p \mid q^n$ which implies $q = p$ therefore the charateristic of $E$ is $p$. However I have no idea how to argue that $E$ is a finite field, the intuition is clear, since $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is finite if adjoint finite number of roots of $x^{n^p} - x$ into it ,it should still be finite?Combined with [this fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4457606/360262), therefore the spliting field of $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is always has charater $p$.

---

Moreover it can be shown all the spliting field of $x^{p^n} - x$ over $\Bbb{Z}_p$ has order $p^n$.

Comment: Splitting field is $GF(p^n)$.

Comment: I didnt delete my comment but somehow it was deleted.